# Inaccurate packet counter in OpenvSwitch

Tags: openflow, sdn, openvswitch

I attempted to send a file from host A to B and capture the packet loss using OpenvSwitch. I connected host A and B to an OpenvSwitch VM separately and connect the two OpenvSwitch VMs. The topology looks like this:

A -- OVS_A -- OVS_B -- B

On each OpenvSwitch VM, I added two very simple flows using the commands below:

ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 in_port=1,actions=output:2

ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 in_port=2,actions=output:1

Then I sent a 10GB file between A and B and compared the packet counts of the egress flow on the sending switch and the ingress flow on the receiving switch. I found that the packet count on the receiving switch is much larger than the count on the sending switch, indicating more packets are received than being sent!

I tried to match more specific flows, e.g. a TCP flow from IP A.A.A.A to B.B.B.B on port C and got the same result. Is there anything wrong with my settings? Or this is a known bug in OpenvSwitch? Any ideas?

BTW, is there any other way to passively capture packet loss rate? Meaning measuring the loss rate w/o introducing any intrusive test flows, but simply use statistics available on the sending/receiving ends or switches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that it was not Open vSwitch's fault. I tested with a UDP stream and packet count was correct. I also used *tcpdump* to capture inbound TCP packets on the switches and the switch at the receiving end had more packets than that at the sending end. The result is consistent with that captured with Open vSwitch's flow counters. I guess I must have missed something important about TCP.